# Replacing Schwinn Rim spokes

Tags: wheels, spokes

I need to replace my rim spokes for Schwinn 28" men and women's bikes which size do I order? and where can I order them? thanks

Comment: As I understand it, it depends on many variables: how the spokes are arranged, how deep the rims are and so on. So I don't think it's possible to answer your question without much more information, beyond saying to measure the spokes you have (there may be multiple lengths) and order those. Specific shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Also, replacing spokes (especially if you're replacing a lot of them) requires quite a lot of skill and knowledge. I'm not trying to insult you but I think it might be beyond the level you're at, based on the way you asked your question. It might be best to take your bike into a bike shop for this repair.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It may be cheaper to buy a new wheelset or depending on the price of the bike (BSO?) it may even be cheaper to buy a whole new bike Than having a wheel rebuilt since it's highly skilled work.

Comment: You need to measure the existing spokes.  There used to be some decent "spoke finder" apps on the web, but haven't seen one in about 10 years.

Comment: The lazy way is to take out one of the unbroken spokes, and measure it.   If you can't measure it, take the unbroken spoke to a LBS and ask for "one of these please" or however many you need.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find the correct length is to measure the existing spokes. Note that the front and rear typically use different lengths and rear has different lengths on left and right side. If there is a disc brake in front, the different sides may have different lengths too. The nipple threads are usually same size, but the middle of the spoke may be thinner, again the easiest way is to use a vernier caliper to measure the thickness.

Shopping questions are frowned upon here, so I'll just leave a hint that spokes are available in most specialized bicycle stores, both online and brick and mortar. You can sure find one.

Replacing the spokes is not very advanced skill but takes some patience at first. There are many instructions online, read at least one set before doing anything and decide whether this is something you want to attempt.